# How to disable searching on few columns but keep sorting enabled in GridView widget column in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to keep sorting enabled on all columns but disable filtering on few specif fields.

For example, I want to `disable` filtering on `first_name` column but `enable` sorting on the same column. How can I do that?

Following code disables the sorting and filtering both.

My code for GridView is:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [
                'attribute'=>'First Name',
                'value'=> 'first_name',
                'filter'=>false,
                //'enableSorting'=>true
            ],
            //'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'street',
            'zipcode',
            'company',
            'created_at',

          ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Also my `search` function code in the CustomerSearchModel::

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Customer::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            //'sort' => ['attributes' => ['first_name','last_name','street','zipcode','company','created_at']],
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'discount' => $this->discount,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'first_name', $this->first_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'last_name', $this->last_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'street', $this->street])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'zipcode', $this->zipcode])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'company', $this->company]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if you have noticed: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the filter model in the grid view configuration if you'd like to **remove all search inputs**:

```
'filterModel' => null,
```

You should than be able to remove not required `$query->andFilterWhere()` declarations in your CustomerSearchModel.

If you'd like to remove **only certain search inputs**, tell the search model that an attribute is not 'active' within the rules:

```
class CustomerSearchModel {
...
public function rules() {
    return [
        // removed 'first_name' from the safe attributes:
        [['last_name','street','zipcode','company','created_at'], 'safe'], // <--- 'safe'
    ];
}
...
}
```

Though 'safe' needs to be used for the declaration, I wrote 'active' since the GridView calls [`DataColumn::renderFilterCellContent()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn#renderFilterCellContent()-detail) (source code: [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/20aa5080189cbacd4180d3b115752817921eb364/framework/grid/DataColumn.php#L184)) which checks if an attribute is an active one with [`$model->isAttributeActive($this->attribute)`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#isAttributeActive()-detail). And those are the ones that are part of the current scenario (the above rule declaration is for the default scenario, attributes marked as 'safe' will be the active ones).

With this you don't need to add `'filter' => false` to the column definition. The standard configuration should be sufficient now:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'street',
            'zipcode',
            'company',
            'created_at',
          ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

The filter input for `first_name` will disappear and the sort option still exists.